# From NSDate how we can store only date using ios?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using below code for display current date

`NSDate *date3 = [NSDate date];`

Console  output is
`2016-12-26 10:33:05 UTC    0x167e90f0`

But I want only day means **26**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly extract components from a date using `NSCalendar`

```
NSInteger day = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%ld", day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below code

Your date is

```
NSDate *date3 = [NSDate date];
```

And use "date3" in below code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *myDayString = [df stringFromDate:date3];
NSLog("Day is - %@", myDayString)
```